# Rails 3 - rails-dbd-mysql gem depend on mysql rather than mysql2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to bundle up the rails-dbd-mysql but it tries to install the old mysql gem rather than the new mysql2 gem. What do I have to do to make this work with mysql2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in diving into the source code, you can do this by modifying the [lib/dbd/Mysql.rb](https://github.com/raphaelcosta/rails-dbd-mysql/blob/master/lib/dbd/Mysql.rb) file. Specifically:

```
begin
    require 'rubygems'
    gem 'mysql'
    gem 'dbi'
rescue LoadError => e
end

require 'dbi'
require "mysql"
require "thread"   # for Mutex
```

Change the `mysql`s into `mysql2`s and reinstall the gem. There might be more scattered throughout the program, so do a Find All to be sure.

**Edit**:
You might try in the [build/rake_task_lib.rb](https://github.com/raphaelcosta/rails-dbd-mysql/blob/master/build/rake_task_lib.rb) file.  Particularly this block of code:

```
DBD_GEM_DEP_MAP = {
    'pg'      => 'pg',
    'mysql'   => 'mysql', #change this to mysql2, or add mysql2 to the list
    'sqlite'  => 'sqlite-ruby',
    'sqlite3' => 'sqlite3-ruby'
}
```

Comment: I've tried that by editing that Mysql.rb file. That section you mentioned seems to be the only place I've found where it's requiring the 'mysql' dependencies. It's not working. The error I get is 'uninitialized constant MysqlError'. I've tried commenting out the line that executes 'MyError = ::MysqlError' but leads to 'uninitialized constant Mysql'.

Comment: Ahhh, there was a build rake task. I did a 'gem build rails-dbd-mysql-0.1.0.gem' from gem's source files and copied it over to a local directory. Then added this to my Gemfile "gem 'rails-dbd-mysql', '0.1.0', :path => 'vendor/gems'". Thanks Andy. Seems I can't award the bounty for another 22 hours. But I'll be testing and monitoring and will reward then.

Comment: Damn, looks like the mysql vs mysql2 api is completely different after digging into this some more. But thanks again for the pointing me to the right track. I may need to either revamp the entire dbd-mysql gem.

Comment: After more research, for anyone who's having the same issue, refactoring the rails-dbd-mysql gem is far too expensive. I've gone with using the 'mysql' gem rather than the 'mysql2' gem.

Comment: Sorry to hear it's given you so much trouble. :(